# Несколько LEFT JOIN для одной и той же таблицы в одном запросе

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте,можно ли в одной SQL запросе написать несколько LEFT JOIN для одной и той же таблицы? Например:

```
"LEFT JOIN goods_attr AS ga   ON ga.goods_id = g.goods_id AND ga.attr_id = 213"
```

и еще один запрос

```
"LEFT JOIN goods_attr AS ga   ON ga.goods_id = g.goods_id AND ga.attr_id = 214"
```

Comment: зачем? если у тебя только attr_id разный? пиши attr_id in (213, 214)

Comment: В запросе есть LIMIT, при помощи которого список товаров разделяется на страницы.
Т.к. у каждого товара 3 атрибута - а атрибуты находятся в другой таблице, LIMIT каждый атрибут защитывает как отдельный товар, в результате не правильно работает пагинация

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Да, такое вполне приемлемо, как я понимаю в Вашем случае один товар может иметь несколько атрибутов хранящихся в одной таблице, приходится конечно же джойнить ее несколько раз что бы получить строку с товаром и всеми атрибутами. Для примера:
таблица с атрибутами:

```
CREATE TABLE `attr` (
   `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` CHAR,
   `type` CHAR,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

таблица с товарами:

```
CREATE TABLE `goods` (
   `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` CHAR,
   `attr_1_id` INT,
   `attr_2_id` INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `attr_1_id` (`attr_1_id`),
   KEY `attr_2_id` (`attr_2_id`),
)
```

запрос будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `goods` as `g`
LEFT JOIN
    `attr` as `a1` ON (`a1`.`id` = `g`.`attr_1_id`)
LEFT JOIN
    `attr` as `a2` ON (`a2`.`id` = `g`.`attr_2_id`)
```

Таким образом для одного товара Вы имеете одну запись в таблице товаров и две записи в таблице аттрибутов, но в рузультирующей выборке получаете одну строку для каждого товара и LIMIT в таком случае должен отрабатывать корректно. И как уже было сказано выше, не забудьте правильно расставить индексы)

Comment: При двойном JOIN из одной таблицы все равно будет Using temporary; Using filesort. Если строк до10к, то без разницы...